# wso2 esb and REST HATEOAS

Tags: rest, hateoas, wso2-esb

I would like to to put in place HATEOAS inside the WSO2 ESB directly but it seems really difficult particularly because I want to use the RFC5988 with HTTP Header Link parameter and Location.

- When doing a POST: Reply with HTTP Header Location of the item created
- When doing a GET: Reply with the HTTP Header Link with the links related to the item get.

As WSO2 documentation is really poor to find something related to this, I ask your help for that.

Should I use Transform mediators?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

To set header fields, you can use the header mediator

See: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Header+Mediator

Example:

```
<header name="Link" value="rel=&quot;deposit&quot; href=&quot;http://somebank.org/account/12345/deposit&quot;">
```

or, as you might want to generate the links from the contents, use expressions:

```
<header name="Link" expression="fn:concat('rel=&quot;deposit&quot; href=&quot;http://somebank.org/account/',//someXQuery,'/deposit')">
```

I have not tried this, and you might need to play around with the escaping and quotation etc., but that's the general way it would work.